# Enable intel p_state Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: intel, governor

How to enable Intel_pstate in Ubuntu 15.04?

Answer (score 4):

In 15.04 it's enabled by default thanks to @solsTiCe  informative notes. you could check that yourself

if `grep -i pstate /boot/config-$(uname -r)` says yes then it's so.

---

To enable intel_pstate in Ubuntu 14.04 , edit the `/etc/default/grub` configuration file with a text editor as root

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And for "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" , add "intel_pstate=enable", like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=enable"
```

Save the file and update Grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your system and to check if intel_pstate is enabled, run the following command:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
```

The command above should return "intel_pstate".

[source and more information](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html)

Comment: There is no need to set boot parameters. It is enabled by default.

Comment: intel_pstate=enable is enabled by default?

Comment: At least in Ubuntu 3.19 kernel `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` gives `intel_pstate` without any boot parameters.

Comment: `cat: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver: No such file or directory` This is my output

Comment: `Linux user 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:01 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: 3.19.0-18 is current. 15 was pre-release and with a lot of bugs.

Comment: This is the ISO downloaded last day

Comment: "Starting with kernel 3.9, the new pstate power scaling driver is used automatically for modern Intel CPUs instead of the other drivers below." Source: Arch wiki

Comment: So what about old kernels? How to enable it?

Comment: In **Ubuntu**: linux (3.16.0-0.2) utopic; urgency=low  **Revert** "SAUCE: intel_pstate -- toggle default to disable"

Comment: theoretically, only trusty (14.04) needs this to be enabled like said above (when you use up to date kernel). And you need to enable it because it has been disabled by a ubuntu patch

Comment: Thanks for reply, in 14.04 I have enabled it, but in 15.04 I was not sure if should I enable it or it it enabled by default.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04 and it is enabled by default. It is 3.16.0-38. It is enabled there too. So no need for doing that.

Comment: @solstice Setting has been reverted. It means now it is default.

Comment: yes. But I did not see the revert patch on trusty kernel changelog. that's why I said that. http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git/log/?qt=grep&q=pstate